# What are the options to build an installer on a build-server without Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, wix, build-server, vdproj

It seems like it's still not possible to build `.vdproj` on a build-server without having Visual Studio installed. However, using Wix seems to be a lot more complicated.

Are there any other options to do the following task:

- Visual Studio 2010 Solution with multiple projects (`.csproj`)
- Many loose content files (not inside assemblies)
- Installer must be built on Build-server without Visual Studio on it (`devenv.exe` / `devenv.com`)
- Installer must create Registry keys
- Installer must associate file extensions with installed product
- Installer must support upgrades (version upgrades)
- Installer should be able to register COM components
- Installer should be able to pre-JIT assemblies

My goal is:

- Effort to maintain installer is low

  - Minimal changes if new project (assembly) is added to solution
  - Ideal: no changes if new content files are added to any of the projects

Maybe I just did not get the point with Wix, but including project output (like in `.vdproj`) seems very complicated.

Any suggestions very much appreciated!

Comment: I use Wix, but it's definitely not "low effort".  Powerful, but it's a new language, a new dialect you need to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I decided to go with Wix. Found out that using [Votive](http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html) it's possible to include project output like in  .vdproj (Binaries, Content, Symbols and even Source Code).

If I run into more complicated situations where this isn't sufficient, I could fall back to some kind of harvester (Heat, Paraffin).

See some more Links in comments below (too little reputation to post more than 1 link in this post).

Comment: Link for Paraffin: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/08/31/zen-of-paraffin.aspx

Comment: An article from a German magazine about Wix and MSBuild covering some common scenarios: http://www.dotnetpro.de/articles/freearticles/pdf/2010-10-MSBuild.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Check out InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition ( Free for Visual Studio 2010 users ).  It has pretty much all the functionality that VDPROJ ( being retired btw ) has and supports silent builds.  You can get one license for your dev box and one license for your build machine pretty easily.